# Simple Javascript prompt validation loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop, do-while

I cant seems to get this to work.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var name = null;
do
{
    var name = prompt("Please enter your full name","");
}
while(name != null);
</script>
```

Comment: `"" != null` is true. You want `while (name == null)` (although I'd recommend `name == ""`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a boolean value:

```
var name = false;
do
{
    name = prompt("Please enter your full name",'');
}
while(!name); // While name is not true
```

Also you were re-declaring the `name` var again on within the `do` loop, remove the `var` in the loop.

Comment: Why introduce another type? Also, the redeclaration is not really a problem.

Comment: Thanks similarly how do i validate the input is a date? i cant seem to get .typeof to work

Comment: @Bergi Good point. I used a type to make the logic easier to understand, but does this have a performance cost? Might be worth it. As for calling `var` again, agreed this isn't a problem but it's still not necessary nor good practice IMO. Cheers

Comment: Using `false` makes everything even more confusing. Now `name` is `undefined` before being initialised, then `false`, then either `null` or a string (depending on what `prompt` returned). I'm not talking about performance costs, but about best practises indeed.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a blank string and press OK, it returns a empty string not null, `null` is returned only when you press cancel.

You can test for truthyness of the returned value

```
var name = null;
do {
  name = prompt("Please enter your full name");
  console.log(name)
}
while (!name);
console.log('done', name)
```